# Access is denied to UNC path in nant zip task when nant task is ran by cc.net, runs ok when nant is ran manually from command line

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

We are running an nant task from cruisecontrol.net. The zip task fails with an error: "Access to path nnnn is denied". The path specified is a UNC path. When we run the same nant task manually from the command line, the task runs successful.

We've also tried to set up a domain user account, and switched the cc.net service to log in as that user.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a domain user account for CCNET is definitely a good starting point to solve the problem. If you're able to access the UNC path interactively logged in as this user, CCNET service should also be.

Cargo cult: Restarting the CI server (server - not service) solved the problem for us in a similar situation.